Question locked since 2020?
It seems this question about lay (householder) practice got locked and forgotten about, but it's still getting bumped by the community bot. That seems odd. Should it be unlocked, revised, or just deleted?

Thank you, I unlocked it.
Normally I shouldn't delete a question unless it's downvoted.
